# HOW TO FIX: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: shading='flat' when X and Y have the same dimensions as C is deprecated since 3.3

Tags: python, matplotlib, speech-recognition, wav, spectrogram

I'm a rookie to python programming but I have been battling these errors for the longest when trying to plot spectrograms from the RAVDESS dataset wav files. This is the code;

```
`for file in range(0 , len(listOfFiles) , 1):
    windows_size = 20
    sample_rate , samples = wavfile.read(listOfFiles[file])
    nperseg = int(round(20 * sample_rate / 1e3))   
    frequencies , times, spectrogram = signal.spectrogram(samples, sample_rate) 
    plt.pcolormesh(times, frequencies, spectrogram)
    plt.imshow(spectrogram)
    plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
    plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
    plt.show()`
```

Here are the errors

```
<ipython-input-16-dc119f345487>:14: WavFileWarning: Chunk (non-data) not understood, skipping it.
  sample_rate , samples = wavfile.read(listOfFiles[file])
<ipython-input-16-dc119f345487>:14: WavFileWarning: Incomplete chunk ID: b'\x00', ignoring it.
  sample_rate , samples = wavfile.read(listOfFiles[file])
<ipython-input-16-dc119f345487>:17: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: shading='flat' when X and Y have the same dimensions as C is deprecated since 3.3.  Either specify the corners of the quadrilaterals with X and Y, or pass shading='auto', 'nearest' or 'gouraud', or set rcParams['pcolor.shading'].  This will become an error two minor releases later.
  plt.pcolormesh(times, frequencies, spectrogram)
```

Sorry that I cant explain the errors better but I'm new to this, any kinda help would be amazing.

Comment: Have you tried what the error suggests: `Either specify the corners of the quadrilaterals with X and Y, or pass shading='auto', 'nearest' or 'gouraud', or set rcParams['pcolor.shading'].`

Comment: Using both `pcolormesh` and `imshow` in the same subplot is quite confusing. Apart from that, `pcolormesh` with the default flat shading gives a warning, because it uses its x and y for the positions of its gridlines, making that there will be one row of cells less in both directions than the product of lenghts of x and y. A workaround could be using `spectrogram[:-1,:-1]`.  It is explained quite well at [this official tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/pcolormesh_grids.html)

Answer (score 7):

Add `shading='auto'`  will resolve this.

So the code should be
`plt.pcolormesh(times, frequencies, spectrogram,shading='auto' )`

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue changing my rcparams: `plt.rcParams['pcolor.shading'] ='nearest'`.
Hope that this will help someone.